# How do I create 3 or four classes of diameter from a range of diameters in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like some code that can help create 3 or 4 classes from a range of diameters of wood. For example if my three classes are 1-10cm, 10-20cm, 20-30cm, I would like to add a column to the below matrix with the three classes. 
e.g.

```
LOGID  DIAMETER
  1       10
  2       30
  3       20
  4       10
  5       8
  6       5
```

to

```
 LOGID  DIAMETER  CLASS
  1       10        1
  2       30        3
  3       20        3
  4       10        2
  5       8         1
  6       5         1
```

Comment: See function `cut`, this question is off-topic, though.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Off topic in what sense?

Comment: Questions that are about how to code in R, but not really about statistics, *even if they are about how to code statistics or code data in preparation for statistics*, are off-topic for CV. They can be on-topic on SO if they have a reproducible example (as this does). We will migrate this for you (*please don't cross-post, this will soon be there*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vincent Guillemot [notes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124537/how-do-i-create-3-or-four-classes-of-diameter-from-a-range-of-diameters-in-r/124539#comment237344_124537), all you need is [?cut](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html).

```
my.data <- read.table(text="LOGID  DIAMETER
  1       10
  2       30
  3       20
  4       10
  5       8
  6       5", header=TRUE)

my.data$CLASS <- cut(my.data$DIAMETER, breaks=c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, Inf),
                     labels=c(1,2,3,4))
my.data
#   LOGID DIAMETER CLASS
# 1     1       10     1
# 2     2       30     3
# 3     3       20     2
# 4     4       10     1
# 5     5        8     1
# 6     6        5     1
```

You may also want to set `ordered_result=TRUE`.